# java.io.FileNotFoundException when copying existing file via FileUtils

Tags: java, tomcat, fileutils

I have a problem. I try to copy a file and I get a FileNotFound exception. Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\.DS\\tmp\\client-" + node_id + ".war");
File dir = new File("D:\\Utils\\Apache\\Tomcat\\webapps");
try {
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, dir);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the exception is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'C:\.DS\tmp\client-022.war' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:1013)
    ...
```

But the file is in that folder.

This code is called from JSF in Tomcat, so maybe it's a problem of Tomcat direcories. The file is generated in previous function via external command using ProcessBuilder, so maybe Java tries to parallel and the ProcessBuilder is finishing after the copying is done.

Also, in another method of the same class this code works perfectly:

```
File file = new File("C:\\.DS\\tmp\\client-" + node_id + ".properties");
File dir = new File("C:\\.DS\\ss\\engines");
try {
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, dir);
    ...
```

Comment: Not sure.  If you have Java 7 or newer, does `java.nio.files.Files` [`copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) have the same problem?  Note that this operates on `Path`s, so you have to use a `File`'s [`toPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--) to get the correct object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that Java is "smart", so Process Builder runs in separate thread (or even process), and to fix my problem I have to change

```
ProcessBuilder pb = ...
pb.start()
```

to

```
ProcessBuilder pb = ...
Process p = pb.start()
p.waitFor()
```